# Nginx redirect problems params

Tags: redirect, nginx

I would like to redirect example.com/e/DownSys/report?classid=123&id=456
to
example.com/e/public/report/?classid=123&id=456

```
rewrite ^/e/DownSys/report?classid=(\d+)&id=(\d+) /e/public/report/?classid=$1&id=$2 permanent;
```

but this is not working...

Answer (score 0):

A question mark in regular expressions is a special character. If you want to match a question mark, escape it with a backslash. The report part in your regular expression now reads :
"repor followed by an optional t followed by classid"

Aside from that, unless you want to only match this specific classid / id combo, you can condense the expression to:

```
rewrite /e/DownSys/(. *)  /e/public/$1 permanent ;
```